# Encrypting SQL Server backups after creation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, encryption

Is there a way to encrypt SQL Server 2012 backups without using [Transparent Data Encryption](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934049.aspx) (aka TDE)?

I don't want to use TDE because I don't want to lose the compression I'm getting on my backups, and I don't want the additional overhead.  It seems like Red Gate and Dell (LiteSpeed) have solutions that can do what I need but I was hoping there was a free solution that's not as complex as adding a step to the maintenance plans that uses the 7-Zip command line and finds the backup file that was just created and encrypts it as a new file and deletes the old file.

Comment: fyi, it will be available in SQL Server 2014. Also, you can encrypt the directory where the backup will be written, using EFS.

Comment: Is using an encrypted drive (ex PGP) that houses the backups an option?

Comment: The backups get stored on a special server called a Data Domain, I'm not sure if we can do encryption there... Stupid question: do the files remain encrypted if you copy them off?

Comment: Answered my own question re: the Data Domain, and it's quite expensive to license.  Files are automatically encrypted by it as you copy them to it, and unencrypted as you copy them off (permissions can be set based on host).  I don't know how EFS differs.

Comment: Consider not free but cheaper solutions like EMS SQL Backup